# How to create AWS Cloudwatch time difference metric from two log lines (Start and end point)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

Trying to create a metric from two log line time difference. first log is start point and second line is end point

**Cloudwatch logs:**

```
Jun 01 14:13:02.931504 Starting point
Jun 01 14:13:08.014407 End point
```

**Expected output**

```
5.082903
```